# WPF CrystalReportsViewer: Change position of sidebar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, crystal-reports

I'm trying to change the position of the left side bar in the crystalreportsviewer WPF element, but I don't know how. I'd like to have the sidebar on top or at the bottom...

[image]

```
<sap:CrystalReportsViewer
                            Name="crystalReportsViewer"
                            Width="auto"
                            Height="auto"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            ShowPrevPageButton="False"
                            ShowStatusbar="False"
                            ShowToolbar="False"
                            SourceUpdated="crystalReportsViewer_SourceUpdated"
                            TargetUpdated="crystalReportsViewer_TargetUpdated"
                            ToggleSidePanel="None" />
```

Comment: Let's have a look at your xaml? ;)

Comment: i added the xaml code to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution: i have a style for a tab control and for tab items...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
   ...
</Style>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
   ...
</Style>
```

i found out, the style for the tabcontrol itself is being used in the cr control, but not the style of tabitems